# Double Automatic Conversion Function definition, gcc error: error: expected type-specifier

Tags: c++, gcc, casting

I have a class with a conversion function in it.

```
class A {
  public:
    operator double() const;
};
```

Now I am defining it outside of the class defintion:

```
operator A::double() const { return 32.5; }
```

I am using MinGW with GCC4.7 on it and I am getting a error:

```
error: expected type-specifier
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a different order:

```
A::operator double() const {return 32.5;}
    ^The function name is "operator double"
```

Comment: Thanks alot man, that worked perfect! Learn something new everyday